# Using a pointer for different arrays?

Tags: c, arrays

I'm having trouble figuring out how to make this Hangman program select the correct array to use based on user input. While I realize that I could easily set up a different `if` statement containing the same code, that seems to be an unnecessary amount of memory to use.  So my question is this: Can I use pointers (or, preferably, something simpler) to represent the array name so that I would only need one sequence of code? I tried to do it through pointers but I believe I was getting something wrong, so if anyone has any tips, I'd greatly appreciate it.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <time.h>


int main(){

char easy_animals[2][3] = {
        { 'c', 'a', 't' }, //0
        { 'd', 'o', 'g' }, //1
      };

char easy_names[2][3] = {
        { 'p', 'a', 't' }, //0
        { 'b', 'o', 'b' }, //1
      };

char u,
    newline,
    dis[16] = { '_', '_', '_', '_' };
    input[10];

int random,
    guesses = 3,
    finish = 0;

_Bool successfulGuess = false;

srand(time(NULL));
random = rand() % 13;

printf("Animals or names?\n");
gets(input);

if (input[0] == 'a'){ // Or any other letter to signify the correct subject

    printf("Animal %d\n", random); // Check random number
    printf("---------\n\n");

    while (guesses > 0){
        finish = 0;
        successfulGuess = false;
        printf("Enter a letter: ");
        u = getchar();
        newline = getchar();

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){

            if (u == dis[i]){
                successfulGuess = true;
                printf("\nYou already guessed this letter.\n");
                printf("\ninput = dis[i]\nGuesses left: %d\n\n", guesses);
                break;
            }
            else if (easy_animals[random][i] == u){
                successfulGuess = true;
                dis[i] = u;
                printf("\ninput = array char\nGuesses left: %d\n\n", guesses);
            }
        }
        printf("\n");

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
            printf("%c", dis[i]);
        }

        if (successfulGuess == false){
            guesses--;
            printf("\n\nbool statement\nGuesses left: %d\n\n", guesses);
        }

        if (guesses == 0){
            printf("Sorry, you've run out of guesses.");
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            if (dis[i] != '_') {
                finish++;
            }
            if (finish == 3){
                printf("\n\nYou guessed the word!");
                guesses = 0;
            }
            else{
                continue;
            }
        }
        printf("\n\n");
    }

}
system("pause");
}
```

Comment: You *could to this with a pointer "switch", but: Functions? Or maybe another array dimension?

Answer (score 0):

`easy_animals` and `easy_names` are both arrays of pointers to `char`. Selecting a word that the user will have to guess simply means selecting one of these pointers, so declare yourself a `char*` that you can use to represent the word:

```
char* wordToGuess;
```

Then assign it to a randomly selected pointer from the relevant array like so:

```
if (/*user selects "animals"*/)
{
    wordToGuess = easy_animals[random];
}
else if (/*user selects "names"*/)
{
    wordToGuess = easy_names[random];
}
else (/*input is invalid*/)
{
    // Prompt the user to re-enter his/her choice.
}
```

Finally, use your new pointer when determining whether or not the user has made a successful guess:

```
else if (wordToGuess[i] == u){
    successfulGuess = 1;
    dis[i] = u;
    printf("\ninput = array char\nGuesses left: %d\n\n", guesses);
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to account for the `for` loop using i to check each column of the array. When I enter a letter that matches, (i.e. "e" in elk), it prints "eee" and then tells me I won the game.

Comment: Nothing about what I suggested above would produce that behavior—I ran your program with these changes and "elk" works fine—so you must have another issue elsewhere.